# Why is rowselect of antd-react selecting all the rows when I click only one row in my table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table built with antd in react. I am getting the data from an API endpoint. Everything else works fine. But when i click one row at the table, all the rows are getting selected. The row selection is working fine with constant data of antd documentation. But when i plug it in my code with dynamic data rendering it just goes crazy and selects every row whenever I click on only one row.
Here is my state :

```
class TabularView extends React.Component {

   intervalID;


   state = {
        selectedRowKeys: [], 
        loading: false,
        data: [],
        columns : [],
        length : '',
        approve : '',
        perc : '',
        icon : <ArrowUpOutlined/>,
        color : '',
        visible: false

         }
```

Here is my other functions for  the row selection

```
 start = () => {
this.setState({ loading: true });
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    selectedRowKeys: [],
    loading: false,
   });
   }, 1000);
   }

  onSelectChange = selectedRowKeys => {
console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', selectedRowKeys);
this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
 }
```

And here is my render part for the rowselection

```
render(){
 const { loading, selectedRowKeys } = this.state;
const rowSelection = {
  selectedRowKeys,
  onChange: this.onSelectChange,
};
 return(
 <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={this.state.columns} dataSource={this.state.data} pagination={{ pageSize: 20 }} />
 )}
```

Comment: could you create a code sandbox?

Comment: @blueseal sorry as it uses my local db to fetch the data and all other functionalites its kind of messed  up situation to create a sandbox. But to be clear, selection works fine if i give it constant data outside of state. But whenever I try to dynamically render data from my api and then set it to my state  to feed to the table then the selection problem occurs.

Comment: After breaking things up, found that all my rows have the same key for  the data so when i select one it selects all the rows because of the same key. But how can i assign keys when fetching data from an api endpoint?

Comment: Solved it! Just needed to set the rowkey to an unique element of the dataindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an unique key prop to each child to avoid this kind of problem

Each and every react chield or any map function you use. If you do not provide a unique key prop to it. It will give a warning.

React always understand it's children by the key prop. So as all the key to the table is the same. As you selecting one row, as the key is same it is selecting all the row. Key prop in react is very much useful for dynamic programming using map function. Please read this for more clarification - [React Key Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `key` on your `dataSource` object.